# It would be or will look

Tags: will-would

Which of the following is correct?

1. Put these sunglasses on – then it would look more realistic.
2. Put these sunglasses on – then it will look more realistic.

Comment: The first wrongly pairs irrealis 'would' with an instruction; 'If you put these sunglasses on   it would look more realistic' shows the normal conditional structure.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. so you can't use would after instruction . can you please elaborate it.

Comment: @Edwin: You can indeed use *would* after instructions, if they're phrased as suggestions: *You might want to put these sunglasses on – then it would look more realistic.*

Comment: @ Peter Shor  thank you for rephrasing .can you replace the phrase without "might" using would

Comment: @Peter The first wrongly pairs irrealis 'would' with an instruction in the usual imperative.